# pyspark - how to select exact number of records per strata using (df.sampleByKey()) in stratified random sampling

Tags: python, pyspark, data-science, apache-spark-mllib

I have a spark dataframe (I am using pyspark)  **'orders'**. Its having following columns in it

```
['id', 'orderdate', 'customerid', 'status']
```

I am trying to do a stratified random sampling using key column as 'status'. My objective is as below

```
>> create a new dataframe with exactly 5 random records per status
```

So the method I have chosen is using .sampleBy('strata_key',{fraction_dict}). But the challenge I have faced is in choosing the exact fraction value for each status, so that every time I should get exactly 5 random records per status. I have followed below method

**1.Created a dictionary for total count per status as below**

```
#Total count of records for each order 'status' in 'ORDERS' dataframe is as below

d=dict([(x['status'],x['count']) for x in orders.groupBy("status").count().collect()])
print(d)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{'PENDING_PAYMENT': 15030, 'COMPLETE': 22899, 'ON_HOLD': 3798, 'PAYMENT_REVIEW': 729, 'PROCESSING': 8275, 'CLOSED': 7556, 'SUSPECTED_FRAUD': 1558, 
'PENDING': 7610, 'CANCELED': 1428}
```

**2.Created a function which generates fraction values needed to fetch exact N records**

```
#Exact number of records needed per status
N=5

#function calculates fraction

def fraction_calc(count_dict,N)
    d_mod={}
    for i in d:
        d_mod[i]=(N/d[i])
    return d_mod

#creating dictionary of fractions using above function
fraction=fraction_calc(d,5)
print(fraction)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{'PENDING_PAYMENT': 0.00033266799733865603, 'COMPLETE': 0.000218350146294598, 'ON_HOLD': 0.0013164823591363876, 'PAYMENT_REVIEW': 0.006858710562414266, 'PROCESSING': 0.0006042296072507553, 'CLOSED': 0.0006617257808364214, 'SUSPECTED_FRAUD': 0.003209242618741977, 'PENDING': 0.000657030223390276, 'CANCELED': 0.0035014005602240898}
```

**3.Creating the final dataframe which is sampled using startified sampling API .sampleBy()**

```
#creating final sampled dataframe
df_sample=orders.sampleBy("status",fraction)
```

But Still I am not getting exact 5 records per status.A sample output is as below

```
#Checking count per status of resultant sample dataframe
df_sample.groupBy("status").count().show()
+---------------+-----+
|         status|count|
+---------------+-----+
|PENDING_PAYMENT|    3|
|       COMPLETE|    6|
|        ON_HOLD|    7|
| PAYMENT_REVIEW|    4|
|     PROCESSING|    6|
|         CLOSED|    6|
|SUSPECTED_FRAUD|    7|
|        PENDING|    9|
|       CANCELED|    5|
+---------------+-----+
```

What should I do here to achieve my objective.

Answer (score 1):

Found a work around

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand,row_number
```

1. Using rand() builtin function for generating column 'key' of random numbers and then assigning a row number to each element of the partition window created over "order_status" column order by 'key'. The code is as below

```
df_sample=df.withColumn("key",rand()).\
withColumn("rnk", row_number().\
over(Window.partitionBy("status").\
orderBy("key"))).\
where("rnk<=5").drop("key","rnk")
```

2. Now I am getting exactly 5 random records per status.A sample output is as below. This out will change for every spark session.

```
#Checking count per status of resultant sample dataframe
df_sample.groupBy("status").count().show()
+---------------+-----+
|   status      |count|
+---------------+-----+
|PENDING_PAYMENT|    5|
|       COMPLETE|    5|
|        ON_HOLD|    5|
| PAYMENT_REVIEW|    5|
|     PROCESSING|    5|
|         CLOSED|    5|
|SUSPECTED_FRAUD|    5|
|        PENDING|    5|
|       CANCELED|    5|
+---------------+-----+
```