# PySpark Proportionate Stratified Sampling "sampleBy"

Tags: pyspark, sampling

**Question: If you implement proportionate stratified sampling using PySpark's sampleBy, isn't it just the same thing as a random sample?**

Edit: there is *proportionate* and *disproportionate* stratified sampling. This question is about the former.

Here's my thinking on this:

Let's say you have 4 groups in a population of total size N = 1000. The groups have proportions:

A: 25%, B: 50%, C: 13%, and D: 12%

Then choosing a proportionate stratified sample of size 100 means choosing a sample consisting of exactly 25 elements from A, 50 elements from B, 13 elements from C and 12 elements from D. (Note: A disproportionate stratified sample would be if you had different sampling ratios than those of the population.)

This is in contrast to doing a random sample where the expected number of elements from A, B, C and D are 25, 50, 13, and 12 respectively.

It would be natural to implement proportionate stratified sampling in PySpark via the `sampleBy` method with fractions

```
fractions = {'A': .1, 'B': .1, 'C': .1, 'D': .1}
```

If this method sampled exactly, you'd have 25, 50, 13 and 12 elements respectively. However, this method is implemented with a Bernoulli trial (coin flipping). For stratified sampling, since all the fractions are identical, so each element is chosen with probability 10%.

In this case doing the Bernoulli trial by strata and then by element is the same as doing this over the entire data set. The latter is just random sampling.

Conclusion: Stratified sampling is "not possible" in this paradigm.
Is this a correct understanding?

I've seen some posts on doing exact sampling using special tricks. I'll see if I can answer my own post using these methods (3) below.

Note: There is a `sampleByKeyExact` method but it is not supported in Python and if it was, the performance and scaling penalties are not ideal.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-statistics.html

Related Posts:

1. Stratified sampling in Spark (Mentions `sampleByKeyExact` which isn't supported in Python)
2. Investopedia Reference
   https://www.investopedia.com/terms/stratified_random_sampling.asp
3. A creative work-around using additional columns that may work.
   [pyspark - how to select exact number of records per strata using (df.sampleByKey()) in stratified random sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61123653/pyspark-how-to-select-exact-number-of-records-per-strata-using-df-samplebykey)

Comment: What point r u trying to make really?

Comment: Edited the topic. Here's the question. If you implement proportionate stratified sampling using PySpark's sampleBy, isn't it just the same thing is a random sample?

Comment: No it is not. Cannot get a databricks cluster going at the moment.

Comment: @thebluephantom Would you able to explain? A stratified sample with sample by is created via a Bernoulli trial same as a random sample. (Proportionate random sampling would set each sampling fraction to the same constant c.) Thanks! :)

Comment: I cannot login to databricks to verify. Will when i can. Also shortage of cloud resources.

Comment: Looked into it. Hoe could the theory of statistics be wrong?

Comment: Will trya test later again. Th3 fraction thing is a little hard to follow in spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some confusion here related to standard definitions. Usually when someone says "stratified sampling", they mean that different classes should get different probabilities. In the example posted above

A: 25%, B: 50%, C: 13%, and D: 12%

A standard stratified sample will give fractions that make sure that in expectation, the sample will have the same number of A,B,C,D. For example

```
fractions = {'A': .2, 'B': .1, 'C': 0.1*50/13, 'D': 0.1*50/12}
```

should give in expectation 5 elements of each class.

In the example given above where

```
fractions = {'A': .1, 'B': .1, 'C': 0.1, 'D': 0.1}
```

The behavior is indeed the same as a simple `sample` with a proportion of 0.1.

The real question is, what are you aiming for? If you want your sample to have the *exact* same proportion of classes as the original, then neither `sample` or `sampleByKey` will provide that. Looking at the documentation, it seems that indeed `sampleByKeyExact` will do the trick.

edit detailing the behavior of `sample` and `sampleByKey`:
For `sample`, a map operation basically goes over every element and based on a random variable decides whether to keep the item (and how many copies in case `withReplacement == True`). This random variable is i.i.d across all elements. In `sampleByKey`, the random variable is independent but has a different distribution based on the key value, or more accurately based on the corresponding value in the `fractions` argument. If the values in `fractions` are identical, this random variable will have the same distribution for all key values - that is why the behavior becomes identical for `sample` and `sampleByKey`.

Comment: Hard to follow. All .1 according to docs seems ok to me. A while since i looked at stats.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling  Seems obvious from this what it is and they use the .x approach.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Note there is proportionate and disproportionate stratified sampling. The former is when the fractions are all equal (my question) and the latter when not. I agree with your post. The reason I posted this question and my reasoning is that I've seen several posts on implementing stratified sampling using "sampleBy" which I think is redundant and perhaps even less efficient. sampleByKeyExact works but it's unsupported in Python. approxQuantile can be used for a deterministic solution but involves edge cases. I have a solution that uses SQL for an exact sample.

Comment: I should mention for disproportionate stratified sampling, I don't think sampleBy's probabilistic nature is a huge issue.